# ArcGIS Calculate Value tool - Python syntax error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, error-000989

I have a feature class within a file geodatabase.

I am using the "Iterate row selection" iterator in Model Builder to read each row in the FC.
I am then using the "Get Field Value" tool to read the following 3 fields from each row:

"Status"

"User"

"Tile"

I then want to use the "Calculate Value" tool to return a string, which I will later use as a file path to copy a specific file.
The logic is as follows:
If "Status" is "Available", return C:\Data\ + "Tile"
otherwise return C:\Data\ + "Tile" + _ + "User"

In the Calculate Value tool, I've put the following into the expression field:

```
a("%Status%", "%User%", "%Tile%")
```

I've put the following into the Code Block:

```
def a(Status, User, Tile):
    if Status == "Available":
        return "C:\Data\" + Tile
    else:
        return "C:\Data\" + "Tile" + "_" + User
```

I have the "Data type" set as string.

My model is as follows:

[image]

I get the following error for my code block:

```
    ERROR 000989
Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 3)
```

I'm happy to have a solution using model builder or using a stand along python script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the `\` character, this way:

```
def a(Status, User, Tile):
    if Status == "Available":
        return "C:\\Data\\" + Tile
    else:
        return "C:\\Data\\" + "Tile" + "_" + User
```

Comment: yeah, or other options: 1. r"C:\data\" + Tile 2. r"C:\"Data"\{0}".format(Tile)

Comment: @mr.adam `r'c:\data\'` is still a syntax error. [Raw strings that end with a backslash still need the final backslash to be represented as `\\`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: @JasonScheirer ah, thanks for pointing that out.  Double slashes would be good here then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as indicated in gcarillo's answer, are the single `\` characters, specially before the closing quote.

Some solutions:

- Use `/` instead of `\`. Windows normally uses backslashes, but forward slashes work too except in the command prompt (cmd.exe).
- Raw strings can be useful, but they don't help with strings that end in a backslash.
- My favorite solution in cases like this: use os.path.join() instead of hardcoded path delimiters.

Example using os.path.join():

```
import os.path

def a(Status, User, Title):
    if Status == "Available":
        return os.path.join("C:", "Data", Tile)
    else:
        return os.path.join("C:", "Data", "Tile_" + User) # Or did you mean os.path.join("C:", "Data", Tile + "_" + User) ?
```